# Objective C code in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I have been trying to convert a piece of code from Objective C to Swift 3.0 syntax with no success. Please find the objective c code below.

**Objective C**

```
 NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "] invertedSet];

 NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Here's what I have tried,

**Swift 3.0**

```
let invalidCharSet : NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ").inverted as NSCharacterSet

let filtered = (replacementString.components(separatedBy: invalidCharSet)as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")
```

The second statement(i.e. filtered = ..) giving the following error,

**Error**

> 'components' produces '[String]', not the expected contextual result
>   type 'NSArray'

Comment: Don't use NSArray, use a Swift array and call .joined on it.

Comment: tried both suggestions...both are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use NSArray, use a Swift array and call `.joined` on it. As a general rule, in Swift, try to avoid using Foundation, better use Swift's own typed tools.

```
let invalidCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ").inverted

let filtered = replacementString.components(separatedBy: invalidCharSet).joined(separator: " ")
```

Comment: Awesome dude...Thanks :)